# Creating an API request with specific parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, python-requests

Currently I am using the following code to scrape https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok for all shoes on the page:

```
import requests
import json

# I used a placeholder for the anchor parameter
uri = 'https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v1?queryid=products&country=us&endpoint=product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(US)%26filter=language(en)%26filter=employeePrice(true)%26filter=attributeIds(0f64ecc7-d624-4e91-b171-b83a03dd8550%2C16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c)%26anchor={}%26consumerChannelId=d9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647%26count=60'

# collect all products
store = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    found_all_products = False
    anchor = 0
    while not found_all_products:
        result = session.get(uri.format(anchor)).json()
        products = result['data']['products']['products']
        store += products

        if len(products) < 60:
            found_all_products = True
        else:
            anchor += 24

# filter by cloudProductId to get a dictionary with unique products
cloudProductIds = set()
unique_products = []
for product in store:
    if not product['cloudProductId'] in cloudProductIds:
        cloudProductIds.add(product['cloudProductId'])
        unique_products.append(product)
```

How do I write this same api request to retrieve  either the mens' shoes from this site or the womens' shoes on the womens shoes page: https://www.nike.com/w/womens-shoes-5e1x6zy7ok ? Which parameter do I need to change?

Comment: I ran your script, it gives both mens and womens

Comment: @bigbounty check my new edit, thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Greg I ran your provided API link in Postman and getting different results for **men** and **women**. All I have changed in the query string parameters is **UUIDs** which is unique in both the cases for **men** it is uuids: **0f64ecc7-d624-4e91-b171-b83a03dd8550,16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c** and for **women** uuids: **16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c,193af413-39b0-4d7e-ae34-558821381d3f,7baf216c-acc6-4452-9e07-39c2ca77ba32**.

If you pass these 2 unique set of uuids in the query string then you will get men and women result separately as there is no other parameter which will define their identity.

Below is the code:

```
import json
import requests

#common query parameters
queryid = 'filteredProductsWithContext'
anonymousId = '25AFE5BE9BB9BC03DE89DBE170D80669'
language = 'en-GB'
country = 'IN'
channel = 'NIKE'
localizedRangeStr = '%7BlowestPrice%7D%E2%80%94%7BhighestPrice%7D'

#UUIDs
uuids_men = '0f64ecc7-d624-4e91-b171-b83a03dd8550,16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c'
uuids_women = '16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c,193af413-39b0-4d7e-ae34-558821381d3f,7baf216c-acc6-4452-9e07-39c2ca77ba32'

def get_men_result():
    url = 'https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v1?queryid=' + queryid + '&anonymousId=' + anonymousId + '&uuids=' + uuids_men + '&language=' + language + '&country=' + country + '&channel=' + channel + '&localizedRangeStr=' + localizedRangeStr
    data = requests.get(url,verify = False).json()
    print(data)

def get_women_result():
    url = 'https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v1?queryid=' + queryid + '&anonymousId=' + anonymousId + '&uuids=' + uuids_women + '&language=' + language + '&country=' + country + '&channel=' + channel + '&localizedRangeStr=' + localizedRangeStr
    data = requests.get(url,verify = False).json()
    print(data)

get_men_result()
print('-'*100)
get_women_result()
```

If you look at the query string which i have created for men and women you will notice that there are 6 common parameters and only uuid is unique. Also if you want you can change country, language etc for more data fetching. Please refer screenshots as well.

**Men**
[image: Men postman result]
[image: Men Actual result]

**Women**
[image: Women postman result]
[image: Women actual result]

Comment: Is there any information on the url params api.nike handles? I need to pull all products, filtered by gender and by category