# Get API Endpoint for new products in Nike.com

Tags: web, web-scraping, server, endpoint, nike

I'm having a BIG ISSUE finding API endpoints for nike.com/mx, I want to get the specific endpoints for new releases, i.e, new products, and want to get products even though they don't have stock, how can I achieve this, I have inspected all endpoints using different network catchers such as POSTMAN, the web browser itself, etc; but no result is made

Note:

I know that the API of nike.com/mx is [www.api.nike.com](http://www.api.nike.com)

Thanks! hope help

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006950/creating-an-api-request-with-specific-parameters/63028508#63028508

Comment: @Vin no since that api endpoind doesnt give me the new released products